# Configuring a new core switch with VLANs

Tags: routing, vlan

I have a core switch that I've purchased second hand, it's foundry switch. I have created 4 VLANs (VLAN1 to VLAN4). I have created a VLAN interface for each VLAN and assigned it an IP in that VLANs range. My problem is I can't get traffic to route between VLANs, one interface can ping another but I can't ping from PC A connected to VLAN1 to ServerB connected to VLAN2. I have enabled RIP?? I haven't set up a routing table as I can't see any commands to add a route, any suggestions on where I should look?

Comment: Hopefully that's RIPv2?

Comment: Err..no, why should I use RIPv2? Ta

Comment: RIPv1 is a classful routing protocol, which means you will have issues if you want to subnet "outside" the "boundaries" of an A,B and C network classes. Then there is also this other nasty issue that RIPv1 does not have any mechanisms to authenticate prefix announcements and this leaves you open to many nasty and hard to troubleshoot security issues. If you really, really, really need RIP, then use v2 or move to other routing protocols such as OSPF (or EIGRP depending on who your hardware vendor is).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I haven't set up a routing table

It won't work until you do this.  If there's no route from one vlan to another, individual packets will be confined to their own vlans, regardless of the destination address.  Look through the docs for your switch to find how to set up the routes.

Comment: Do I set the routes up in RIP or is the routing table separate from the routing protocol? Thanks

Comment: @james it's separate

Comment: OK thanks, I must be looking in the wrong place for the routing table.

Comment: If the four VLANs are in the same switch and each VLAN has an IP address assigned (i.e. a "VLAN interface" in Cisco "parlance") so each of these interfaces appear as "connected interfaces" in your switch's routing table, then there is no need to run a routing protocol. It is enough that each device in each of the four VLANs/networks to have as a default gateway the IP address assigned to it's VLAN for them to have connectivity. Now if you want to connect to networks not directly connected, then you will need a routing protocol (or only a default route, depending on your topology et.al.)